# Swift : HTTP 500 Error when calling from callback

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code I am using( the login part executes successfully, "Logged in successfully" is readable in the console )

```
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {
    print("loginIsExecuting")
    Server.Login(email: inputEmail.text!, password: inputPassword.text!, handlerDone:{
        print("Logged in successfully")
        Help.getData();
    }, handlerFailed: {
        print("===Failed to log in ")
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.displayAlert()
        }
    })
}
```

**Help.swift**

```
import Foundation

class Help {
static func getData(){
    let urlString = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.16/~peterlizak/Secway/web/app/get-auditor")
    if let url = urlString {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                print(responseString) //JSONSerialization
            }
        }
        task.resume()
   }
 }
}
```

While executing I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error.
This is from the apache log :

```
 192.168.1.16 - - [13/Oct/2017:12:04:30 +0200] "POST /~Myname/Myapp/web/app/get-auditor HTTP/1.1" 500 495
```

Using the same code only calling ***Help.getData()*** after ***Server.login*** (not in the callback function) is working when I execute the code only once. But if I click the button again to trigger ***loginAction()*** ,again the function behaves as it does in the first version: the login executes, *"Logged in successfully"* is in the console, but when the code tries to execute the HTTP request it gets the same HTTP 500 error.(Also that solution is not acceptable because I must call first login and after the data)

I am using symphony for the backend and this is my simple code I try to request :

```
/**
 * @Route("/get-auditor" , name="get_auditor")
 */
public function getAuditorInfoAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'description' => 1,
        "header" => 1
    );
    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

**EDIT:**

**Server.Login**

```
static func Login(email: String , password: String ,handlerDone:@escaping ()  -> Void,handlerFailed:@escaping ()  -> Void) {
     print("=== Server Login ===")
    let url = URL(string: "\(self.baseUrl)~peterlizak/Secway/web/app/login")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let parameters = ["email": email, "password": password]

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    CallService(request: request, handlerDone:{ json in
            ParseLoginResponse(json: json)
            handlerDone()
    }, handlerFailed: {
          handlerFailed()
    } )
}
```

**Server.CallService**

```
static func CallService(request:URLRequest,handlerDone: @escaping (_ json:[String:Any])  -> Void,handlerFailed: @escaping ()  -> Void)
{
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            handlerFailed()
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            handlerFailed()
            return
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        var json:[String:Any]
        do {
            json = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as! [String:Any]
        }
        catch {
            print("json error calling "+(request.url?.absoluteString)!+" =\(String(describing: error))")
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
            handlerFailed()
            return
        }
        let status = json["status"] as! Int
        if status != 0{
            handlerDone(json)
        }
        else{
            print("status is 0 = \(responseString!)")
            handlerFailed()
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 500 is an **internal server error** and not a client error. There will be some exception in related method in server for this API call. This error usually means something goes wrong in the server and need to look into the error trace.

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly likely sending request to the wrong url since in the code you have `/~peterlizak/Secway` and error response has `/~Myname/Myapp`

Comment: Sorry for that , I edited that in the apache log , it is correct in the app

Comment: can you share when `handlerDone:` is called in `Server.Login`

Comment: is `ParseLoginResponse(json: json)` required to be finished before `Help.getData();` is called?

Comment: Yes, I have to retrieve the Session ID

Comment: Ok, and is `ParseLoginResponse(json: json)` sync or async meaning, will `ParseLoginResponse(json: json)` be completed when next line is called `handlerDone()`

Comment: Its an async function

Comment: Then there is your answer...if `ParseLoginResponse(json: json)` is async then `handlerDone()` will be called and `Help.getData();` will be executed before `Session ID` is set. So make function sync or wait until it finished before `handlerDone()` is called

Comment: I am using open routes now, everything is accessible without using Session ID. But I tried to delete  ParseLoginResponse(json: json) to see what happens, still the same error

Comment: Try this: leave `ParseLoginResponse(json: json)` in and wrap `handlerDone()` to be executed after a second like so: `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)) {
            handlerDone()
        }`

Comment: Damn, I have no more suggestions other than installing Charless app and see all requests and responses to your server and see what your requests and paths are and responses from server...

Comment: Last try : I found out that calling twice Help.getData() will make it work ! First it will return error 500 but second time it returns the correct data. I am testing on localhost, does it affect that ? (Anyway thank you for your effort helping me :) )

Comment: Should not matter if it is localhost or server...something is up with server if it does not work the first time and works the second...or some http headers or fields are not set correctly in the first request (Charles to the rescue for that)